# TinyMCE toolbar sticky with an offset

Tags: tinymce

I have an app which has a floating header. TinyMCE renders the sticky toolbar underneath this when I scroll because it positions it fixed at top: 0

Is there a mechanism/hack to add offset to this so that the sticky toolbar can sit below the header?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not the perfect solution.

```
div.tox-tinymce--toolbar-sticky-on div.tox-editor-header {
top: 40px !important;
}
```